# Which of Adam’s sons married which of his daughters?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, parashat-bereishit, adam, twins

According to Rashi to Bereishis 4:1-2, Kayin was born with a twin sister, and Hevel was born with two triplet sisters. As Rashi to Vayikra 20:17 explains, Kayin married his sister in order that the world could be populated.

Which sister(s) did Kayin marry? Did he marry his own twin, or did he marry one of Hevel’s triplets?

Did Hevel marry before he was killed? If yes, which one did he marry? If no, which one was he supposed to?

What about Sheis? Rashi expounds each time את appears in 4:1-2 as a reference to another sister, but no such word appears in either 4:25 or 5:3 regarding his birth (though it does appear in both regarding his name). Since he therefore wasn’t born with a twin, did he marry Kayin’s twin sister or did he marry one of Hevel’s? Or perhaps he married a female descendant of Kayin’s?

These questions are specifically in Rashi’s opinion that Kayin married his twin sister. If there are alternative explanations as to whom each brother married that might possibly fit into Rashi’s opinion, I will only accept such an answer if you can demonstrate that Rashi holds that way as well.

Comment: "Since he therefore wasn’t born with a twin, did he marry Kayin’s twin sister or did he marry one of Hevel’s?" or his (great-)*niece?  or a sister who wasn't anybody's twin?

Comment: @Heshy As far as we know the only daughters that Adam had were someone’s twin. I’ll edit in your point about potentially being a niece.

Comment: "As far as we know the only daughters that Adam had were someone’s twin." - he lived 930 years and had to populate the world!  I think it's unreasonable to assume Adam had exactly the 3 sons mentioned in Chumash and the 3 daughters mentioned in the midrashim and no more children.  If you're going in that direction you might as well assume all the generations had exactly the 2 sons and 2 daughters explicitly mentioned in ויולד בנים ובנות.  It's possible, but there's no reason it has to be the case.

Comment: Probably if there was a niece he wouldn't have been allowed to marry his sister.

Comment: @Heshy Even ויולד בנים ובנות may refer to his entire life, not just the last 800 years.

Comment: Hevel did not have triplet sisters; only twins(two wives/sisters).

Comment: @chachamNisan Hevel and his two sisters make up a set of triplets. If the two sisters were only twins, Hevel wouldn’t have been born at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Rashi is quoting the opinion in Medrash Rabba Which says that Kayin had 1 twin sister and Hevel had 2 twin sisters:

> אָמַר רַבִּי הוּנָא תְּאוֹמָה יְתֵרָה נוֹלְדָה עִם הֶבֶל, זֶה אוֹמֵר אֲנִי נוֹטְלָהּ שֶׁאֲנִי בְּכוֹר, וְזֶה אוֹמֵר אֲנִי נוֹטְלָהּ שֶׁנּוֹלְדָה עִמִּי, וּמִתּוֹךְ כָּךְ וַיָּקָם קַיִן.
>   An extra twin sister was born with Hevel, Kayin said i should marry her because i am the firstborn, Hevel said i should marry her because she was born with me and through this dispute Kayin got up and killed Hevel

We see that Kayin and Hevel were both married to their twins, and that Hevel didn't get a chance to marry his second twin until he got killed. We also see later after Kayin killed Hevel and Hashem banished him from humans in Bereishis 4,17 וַיֵּדַע קַיִן אֶת אִשְׁתּוֹ i.e that Kayin knew his (singular tense) wife which implies that his original wife was allowed to remain with him and that he never ended up taking another wife. So According to the Medrash Rabbah which Rashi is reffering to , **Hevel's second twin married neither Kayin or Hevel**.

It could be that this second twin ended up marrying Sheis, or it could be that Sheis married other daughters of Adam as it says וַיּ֥וֹלֶד בִּדְמוּת֖וֹ כְּצַלְמ֑וֹ which clearly indicates the birth of more children at the time of Sheis' birth. Indeed many women must have been available, as Lemech married 2 wives in spite of the fact that only one את was written at the birth of Chanoch, Irod, Mechiyael, Mesushael and lemech. So if each of the above names married their twin, Lemech must have got his second wife from somewhere.